# js - how to manage multiple buttons depending on eachother

Tags: javascript

This question is more about idea than programming trouble.
Consider situation that you have 20 buttons on screen. It is some kind of admin page where you can turn on some functionalities for users but depending on properties of current user some functionalities may be turned on or off. Also some functionalities impact on other functionalities:

Consider such 4 buttons:

```
sex (male/female) 
age (child, adult, old) 
wear (pants, dress, hat) 
alcohol (vodka, beer) 
drive (yes, no)
```

So selecting male, turns off possibility to wear dress.
Selecting child turns off possibility to drink any alcohol and also driving.
Selecting any alcohol turns possibility for driving.

So you can see that every button may have influence of possibility of selecting any other button. Here the examples are quite simple but i am looking for solution that is expandable and easy to read. I would like to avoid something like:

```
$('.age').click(function () {
        if ( age == "child") { alcohol = disabled; driving = disabled }
})
$('.alcohol').click(function () {
        if ( alcohol == disabled ) { driving = disabled }
})
```

With more complexity it is very hard to maintain.

So here comes the question: can you provide any smart idea to manage multiple buttons that stay in some relationship between eachother in js/jquery? I mean sth like "create 2-dimensional array of every button (column) and all other buttons (rows), and where they cross put true for visibility, and false for not visibility" or something like this?

regards,
Kalreg.

Comment: Depending on how complex a system you are really building, application state/view frameworks like React or Angular are going to save you from a potential game of whack-a-mole trying to manage all this yourself via jquery.

Comment: Agree with 1252748 - the smart idea to manage this sort of complexity is to use a framework that is already built to do this kind of thing. Something in vue.js might look like `<section id="drive" v-if="age!=child && alchohol=''">` or `<section id="drive" v-if="canDrive">` where _canDrive_ is a computed property in the vue "model".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I'm interpreting this correctly.

The process you are discussing with regards to managing a relationship between inputs/buttons etc is commonly known as state management.

There are several Javascript libraries/frameworks that excel at exactly this. The rise of front end libraries frameworks such as Vue/React/Angular have risen to popularity over jquery/standard JS for this exact reason. As the dependency's between events become more complicated switching to a library that excels at state management will make your life much easier. A common meme/picture that is used to exemplify this is as follows.

[image]

You might want to take a look at something like this. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html

or

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

If you have specific questions please let me know. Sorry to post links as an answer but in your case I think it makes the most sense.

Comment: I've read about react and have to admit that idea of states seems to be solution to my problem. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: I've read about react and have to admit that idea of states seems to be solution to my problem. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: No problem! Good luck.